# getting wrong data from RoomDB. GetCount() using CoroutineScope is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a login app which uses Navigation Activity, JetPack and RoomDB. It has LoginFragment, LoginVieweModel, LoginDatabase, LoginDao and login Repository. I don't know the correct syntax to get UserCount from RoomDB.

The whole app is located in GitHub at https://github.com/msyusuf/LoginFragNavActivity.git.

Code in LoginDao is

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loggedin_user_table")
suspend fun getLoggedInUserCount(): Int
```

Code in LoginViewModel is

```
fun getUserCount(): Int {
    var count: Int = 99
    viewModelScope.launch {
        count = loginRepository.getUserCount()
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In LoginViewModel.getUserCount(): count = $count")
    }
    return count
}
```

The fun getUserCount() does not have count from repository, it 99 which I used to initialize the count variable.

Comment: Your launched coroutine will not happen until after `getUserCount()` has returned. Have your viewmodel provide the data via some reactive mechanism, such as by having `getUserCount()` itself be a `suspend` function.

Comment: Some explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370029/506796

Comment: I found a solution on Stack Overflow ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057041/how-to-get-the-row-count-of-room-database-in-android)

Comment: @Saleem I review answers by the link you provided, and most of them seems not good to me, except answers where `LiveData` is used, I wouldn't use them. There is a simpler solution, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `getUserCount()` function of `LoginViewModel` class a coroutine, launched using `launch` builder, will be executed after the function returns. You should think about how you want to use the data. If you want it to be used just as an input data for some another calculations then it make sense to make the `getUserCount()` function `suspend`:

```
suspend fun getUserCount(): Int {
    val count: Int = loginRepository.getUserCount()
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In LoginViewModel.getUserCount(): count = $count")
    return count
}
```

If you want it to be displayed in UI you can make it `suspend` like above and call it in a coroutine using [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope):

in `Activity`/`Fragment`

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val count = viewModel.getUserCount()
    // update UI
}
```

Another alternative is to apply reactive approach using [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) or Kotlin [`Flow`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow)

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. At the moment, I have something that works, so I will stay with it and deal with the next problem. Later, when I get a chance, I will revisit. Thank you for you help.